# Swift ui stacks causing gap at the top of the screen when frame should be first

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In Swift ui I have a tabview and am going to my profile test page but in the simulator it displaying in the middle of the page.

```
var body: some View {

        VStack() {
            Text("Welcome")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
             ZStack {
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
               .fill(.red)
                   VStack {
                           Image("murry")
                                          .clipShape(Circle())
                                          .shadow(radius: 10)
                                          .overlay(Circle()
                                         .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5))
                                   Text("Murry GoldBerg")
                           
                           HStack{
                               Text("Following:0").foregroundColor(.white)
                               Text("Followers:2").foregroundColor(.white)
                               Text("Kids:0").foregroundColor(.white)
                           }
                         

                       }
                       .padding(20)
                       .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                   }
                   .frame(width: 450, height: 250)

               }
    Spacer()

        }
        
}
```

My Code as to how am inserting my views in the tab view not showing it all as no need just a snippet

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView{
        HomeView()                .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")
                
            }
            
        ProfileView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                Text("Profile")
                
            }
        
        StatsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus").renderingMode(.original).padding()
                Text("Plus")
                
            }
   }
```

[image]

Even on a real device it is doing the same so I no its not just the simlutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is there is only one `VStack` so it will be default the main layout of the view. Default VStack if has only one view is from center view.

You just need add another `VStack` to cover your `VStack` then it will layout from top

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack() {
            Text("Welcome")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
             ZStack {
                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                     .fill(.red)
                 VStack {
                     Image("murry")
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .overlay(Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5))
                     Text("Murry GoldBerg")
                     HStack{
                         Text("Following:0").foregroundColor(.white)
                         Text("Followers:2").foregroundColor(.white)
                         Text("Kids:0").foregroundColor(.white)
                     }
                  }
                 .padding(20)
                 .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            .frame(width: 450, height: 250)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks very much still learning like your self.